# Inserting a string in the middle of another string or splitting the string into two parts

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, visual-studio

I wanted to know how I could place a `String2` inside of another `String1` if `String1` reached a certain length. For Example,

```
if(Consolas.MeasureString(text).Length() > 30) {
    //Add String2 into String1 at the length of 30.
}
```

So if `String1 = aaaa` and two of the a's were greater than `30` then it would be changed to `aa1aa`. I thought of two ways such as splitting the `String1` into `String1` and `String3` and then adding the `String2` into `String1` then adding `String3` back on. The other way would just be to insert `String2` into `String1` at length `30`. I'm not entirely sure how this could be done.

Comment: what do you want to achieve by this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append(string1.Substring(0,string1.Length/2));
sb.Append(string2);
sb.Append(string1.Substring(string1.Length/2,string1.Length- string1.Length/2));

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

This is a [somehow working feedle of the case](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)

Comment: So if i'm understanding this correctly you are taking half the length of the string, adding the second string, then putting the second half of the first string on. I was looking for it to append at a specified length, however, I think it will work with some adaptations.

Comment: yes, actually it adds half of `string1` then add `string2` then adds the remaining part of `string1`

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly when the length of a string goes beyond 30 characters you want to insert another string at the index 30.

```
string text ="";

if (text.Length >= 30)
{
  text  = text.Insert(30, "string2");
}
```

Comment: It was if the length of the string in pixels hence Consolas.MeasureString() so if the string measures up to 30px then it would insert the other string.

Answer (score 0):

```
string str1 = "ABCDEFGH";  
string str2 = "= I'm Added =";  

if (str1.Length > 5)  
{str1 = str1.Insert(5, str2);}
```

Comment: => str1 = str1.Insert(str1.Length / 2, str2);                                                       U can try if u want to put in middle....